# Sequelize Postgres createdAt time with timezone, saving and getting date and time in a format

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

[image of the user table, createdAt only saving the time and there is no date information with time and timezone field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/skTcZ.png)I am using sequelize and postgres, when I save a user or value in DB postgres automatically adds createAt and upDatedAt with timestamp, when I retrieve the value of createdAt it gives me "06:15:41.037000+00:00", my question is how to display it in formatted date? Please help me. I tried moment.js to convert but it gives me "Invalid Date" error. I have searched many examples but unable to understand the issue.

[this is the response I get when I make api call, but unable to convert the createdAt values to meaningful date as there is no date, only time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k5QSz.png)

Answer (score 1):

i grabbed this quickly from another answer... check out how it was done here

```
const Test = sequelize.define('test', {
                // attributes
                name: {
                    type: DataType.STRING,
                    allowNull: false
                },
                createdAt: {
                    type: DataType.DATE,
     //note here this is the guy that you are looking for                   
                  get() {
                        return moment(this.getDataValue('createdAt')).format('DD/MM/YYYY h:mm:ss');
                    }
                },
                updatedAt: {
                    type: DataType.DATE,
                    get() {
                        return moment(this.getDataValue('updatedAt')).format('DD/MM/YYYY h:mm:ss');
                    }
                }
```

Comment: This is not working, because when I get the data from the database, because as the result does not contain any date only time "06:15:41.037000+00:00", I dont know why I am not getting any date

Comment: Well what does your model look like, you need to alter your original post and add the code

Answer (score 0):

I usually create "created_at" and "updated_at" manually in my model and migration rather generated from sequelize and the value of them is sequelize.Date. Here's the code for that :

```
  createdAt: {
    type: Sequelize.DATE,
    field: 'created_at',
  },
  updatedAt: {
    type: Sequelize.DATE,
    field: 'updated_at'
  }
```

and timestamps false to block generate from sequelize

```
timestamps: false
```

Answer (score 0):

**For MYSQL**

You can use sequelize function to get the date only with time cropped

```
model.findAll({
      attributes: [
        [sequelize.fn('DATE', sequelize.col('createdAt')), 'DateOnly']
      ]
    })
```

this will help you get the date only.

**For postgres**

try to replace the sequelize function by this.

```
sequelize.fn('date_trunc', 'day', sequelize.col('created'))
```